# How to use Kruskal-Wallis to check if continuous variable Y has correlation with categorical variable X?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, kruskal-wallis-test

I used Kruskal-Wallis on my data that has a continuous Y variable and categorical X variable (more than 2).

I got the following result:
Statistics=784.547, p=0.0000 with alpha: 0.05.

What does this mean? Does this mean that there is some correlation between my X and Y variables?

Comment: Loosely speaking, it means that the medians of $Y$ are not the same for every category in $X$, quite similar to an ANOVA F-test. Formal “correlation” is a bit of a tricky notion for a categorical variable, but a more general “dependence/independence” makes more sense. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, I'd want to check if a categorical variable is correlated with my Y (continuous) variable. All I saw is to use Kruskal-Wallis. Then I used it here and got a ton of p=0.0000. What does having 0.000 mean?

Comment: That’s the p-value, so it provides considerable evidence against your null hypothesis. What is your null hypothesis? // It is important to state your goal in conducting this test. What do you want to demonstrate? KW is not quite testing correlation (but it kind of is, too). Do you want to show that $Y_1, Y_2,..., Y_k$ have different means? Different medians? Different distributions?

Comment: @Dave what would be the null hypothesis of using KW on X, Y?

Comment: Loosely speaking, it means that $Y$ has the same median in every $X$ category. (The true null and alternative are trickier than this, but this explanation is okay for now and how most people think of KW, anyway.)

Comment: @Dave Kruskal-Wallis is only an omnibus test for median difference under additional (and quite stringent) assumptions. Strictly, and properly speaking, the KW test is an omnibus test of $\text{H}_{0}\text{: }P(X_i > X_j) = 0.5$ for at least one group $i\ne j$, and for $\text{H}_{\text{A}}\text{: }P(X_i > X_j) \ne 0.5$. In plain language: the null is that the probability of a randomly observed value in one group exceeding a randomly observed value in another group is not equal to one half, for at least two different groups.

Answer (score -1):

I will use fictitious data simulated in R to illustrate a Kruskal-Wallis test.
Maybe my data are sufficiently similar to yours that the illustration will be
helpful to you.

Suppose I have 75 subjects randomized with 25 each into three treatment groups.
Treatment group is the categorical variable. Increases $Y_{ij}$ in scores
during treatment are used to measure the effect of treatment on subject $j$ in group $i.$ The increases are not normally distributed, so a Kruskal-Wallis test
is used instead of a one-way ANOVA.

Summaries of the scores within each treatment are shown below, along with a
boxplot of the scores in each group.

```
summary(y1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  11.73   25.83   41.07   44.51   63.94  104.58 
summary(y2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  27.79   40.36   47.62   52.79   61.34   94.57 
summary(y3)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  29.89   49.07   69.04   74.90   86.37  177.57 

y = c(y1,y2,y3)
x = rep(1:3, each=25)
boxplot(y~x, col=c("red","green2", "blue"), pch=19, notch=T)
```

[image]

The notches in the sides of the boxes are nonparamteric confidence intervals
calibrated so that, when comparing two groups, overlapping notches may suggest
no significant difference. (Roughly speaking we should not expect a significant
difference in medians between groups 1 and 2, we might see a significant difference between
groups 2 and 3, and we will likely see a difference between groups 1 and 3.)

Non-linear normal probability plots indicate that the data are not normal.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
 qqnorm(y2, col="red"); qqline(y2, lwd=2)
 qqnorm(y3, col="green2"); qqline(y3, lwd=2)
 qqnorm(y3, col="blue"); qqline(y3, lwd=2)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

Overall, the three samples are moderately right skewed. A Kruskal-Wallis test
shows significant differences among the three groups, with a P-value near $0.$

```
kruskal.test(y ~ x)

        Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  y by x
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 14.458, df = 2, p-value = 0.0007253
```

*Ad.hoc* Wilcoxon ranks sum tests comparing pairs of groups, shows the
sample pattern of differences as suggested by the boxplot notches.
Using the Bonferroni method of avoiding false discovery in such *ad hoc*
tests, we judge two groups to be significantly different if P-values are
below $0.017.$ [There are alternative methods of doing these *ad hoc* tests, but
this one seems adequate for the data at hand.]

```
wilcox.test(y1, y2)$p.val
[1] 0.1361038
wilcox.test(y2, y3)$p.val
[1] 0.00751265
wilcox.test(y1, y3)$p.val
[1] 0.0002854449
```

If we look at empirical CDFs (ECDFs) of the data in the three groups, plots with
ECDFs shifted to the right (thus plotting below) indicate a group that gives
generally higher values than another ('stochastically dominates' it). Even if one
feels uncomfortable interpreting the Kruskal-Wallis test as a comparison of
population medians, one can see that group 3 (blue) dominates group 1 (red).

```
plot(ecdf(y1), xlim=c(10,180), col="red",
       main="ECDFs of Three Groups")
 lines(ecdf(y2), col="green2")
 lines(ecdf(y3), col="blue")
```

[image]

*Note:* In case my fictitious data are of interest, here is how they were simulated in R:

```
set.seed(2021)
y1 = round(rgamma(25, 6, .14),2)
y2 = round(rgamma(25, 6, .11),2)
y3 = round(rgamma(25, 6, .07),2)
```